# How can I get a navigable (editable?) buffer with vim's `messages`?

Tags: vim, vim-plugins, error-logging

So, if I get an error from a plugin, I'd like to be able to report that error on GitHub or similar.

Unfortunately, it's not mouse-selectable; and after appearing and asking me to hit RETURN, it seems gone forever.

1. I've discovered that I can cause the errors to appear *again* using `:messages` or `:3messages` or similar; but they appear in the same fashion: un-selectable, useless.
2. Another Stacker [asked](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/how-do-i-copy-the-error-message-i-get-from-ycm) a similar question, which yielded the useful command `:let @+=v:errmsg` — but that only captures the *very last* line of the messages; many errors I see consist of *multiple* lines, all of which I'd like to select.

Please help me either A. turn a `:messages` window into a buffer, so I can use normal likewise-visual selection to copy what I want to report outside of Vim, or at least B. construct something I can throw into my `.vimrc` that will copy *all* of the lines of the most recent error onto my clipboard.

Thanks! `(=`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer by Heptite is a good way to do this using built-ins. If you're okay with using a plugin, my [bufferize](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/bufferize.vim) plugin automates the process a bit. Lets you just do:

```
:Bufferize messages
```

In order to get a preview buffer with the contents of that command's output.

As a side note, I'm surprised the `:messages` output is not selectable. I guess maybe you're using Vim with a GUI? With terminal Vim, you can select, and then middle-click-paste the content.

Comment: I'm not usually one for plugins over built-in features, but the built-in way in this case is so obtuse, and the plugin is so simple and *ideal* for exactly this situation. Have u an check, @Andrew! Great tool, I've been using it since this reply, and now it's a baked-in part of my Vim process. (=

Comment: Thanks, always happy to hear someone likes a plugin of mine :).

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
:put = execute('messages')
```

---

Explanation:

- `:put {register}` puts the contents of the register at the cursor location (like `p` in normal mode)
- `execute('messages')` is a vimscript function that executes an Ex command, and captures it's output
- `={vimscript expression}` is the expression register, who's value is the result of the vimscript expression

So the above captures the output of the `:messages` command in the expression register, and puts the contents of the expression register at the cursor's location.

See `:h quote=`, `:h :put`, `:h execute()`

Comment: Code without any explanation is useless. Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: This is pretty straightforward. Open a new empty buffer and run the command -- it will paste the output of `:messages` command in to the current buffer.

Comment: This approaches truncates messages. It does not work well if you have one long message across multiple screens

Comment: Thanks @NaotoTanaka, this was great!  Much more convenient than `:redir`.  I added a short explanation if that's good with you.

Comment: @matt0089 Thanks a great explanation!

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
:redir > messages.txt
:messages
:redir END
:e messages.txt
```

You can suppress output to the display while still capturing the messages output by changing `:messages` to `:silent messages`.